# Why am i getting java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence exception

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am running a simple update statement in my java code to an oracle database (JDBC call) and it updates when record is found but when record doesn't exist i get  " java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01002: fetch out of sequence" exception. Here is my code, why exception? Where should I improve it. Code sample would be very helpful.

```
public String preformUpdate(String someValue){
    ResultSet rs;
    String result = "Update failed record not found.";
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    try{
        conn = DBConnect.getInstance().dbOracleConnect();   

        StringBuffer sbUpdate = new StringBuffer();
        sbUpdate = new StringBuffer("UPDATE sometable ");
        sbUpdate.append("SET value1 = ? ");
        sbUpdate.append("WHERE value2 = ?" );

        ps = conn.prepareStatement(sbUpdate.toString());  
        ps.setString(1, "0");
        ps.setString(2, someValue);

        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        if (rs.next()){
            result = "Value updated";               
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        JDBCHelper.close(cs);   
        JDBCHelper.close(conn);         
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I'm not a Java dev, but from what I know of other languages, I think the rs.next() may be the problem, as an update query probably returns no result set, so the next() fails...

Comment: Haven't you ever coded an SQL insertion in Java before?

Comment: I am just learning, sorry if this is a silly question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `executeUpdate()` instead of `executeQuery()` since you're NOT firing a SELECT.

```
int numberOfRowsAffected = ps.executeUpdate();
```

This method returns the number of rows actually updated in the database.

Comment: Ravi Thapliyal this takes care of the exception but when it finds a record to update is just hangs on that line int numberOfRowsAffected = ps.executeUpdate(); and i am updating just a single record.

Comment: Hangs as in the program does not terminate? Does it throw any exception on the console? Could you update your code block for added clarity? Also, is the data type of value1/2 varchar in database?

Comment: It just hangs no exceptions and program doesn't terminate

Comment: int numberOfRowsAffected = ps.executeUpdate();
  
   if (numberOfRowsAffected != 0){
    result = "record updated";
   }

Comment: Hanging mid execution indicates that the table has probably been locked and hence your update is in wait. If possible restart the database. Make sure that no other database transaction is using this table while you try to update it.

Comment: You are correct, i was locking the table. Works now, thanks for your help Ravi.